# Microsoft Test Manager running coded UI Tests

Tags: selenium, coded-ui-tests, microsoft-test-manager

We have recently automated some "Coded UI Tests" (running in the selenium framework) which are run from within Microsoft Test Manager (MTM).  However, I am struggling to find out how MTM can pass parameters (such as the URL of the application under test) through to the coded UI tests.  It seems to me that this would be a fairly typical usage pattern, but I am struggling to see how it can be achieved.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 2):

Your after Data Driven Coded UI Tests

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mathew_aniyan/archive/2009/03/17/data-driving-coded-ui-tests.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624082.aspx

If your linking yout Coded UI Test to a Test Case you can use the test cases parameters to feed the data into the coded ui test to drive it.